# Excel 2010 - Multiple drop downs using data validation and logic

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, sumifs

I have a table which contains a list of data I wish to use with dynamic drop down lists. My data looks as follows:

```
Group   Strength    RX  QTY QTY/RX
Class1  Strength1   1   5.4     5.4
Class2  Strength1   2   10.8    5.4
Class4  Strength1   3   16.2    5.4
Class1  Strength1   3   16.2    5.4
Class1  Strength2   4   42      10.5
Class2  Strength2   2   16.8    8.4
Class4  Strength2   3   25.2    8.4
Class2  Strength4   2   38.4    19.2
Class1  Strength4   8   163.2   20.4
Class2  Strength4   12  182.4   15.2
Class3  Strength4   2   38.4    19.2
Class1  Strength4   8   124.8   15.6
Class1  Strength3   1   24      24
Class2  Strength3   6   72      12
Class1  Strength3   5   60      12
```

Using the first two columns as drop down lists i.e. drop down list 1 selects from the 'Group' and then drop down list chooses the metric from columns 3-5. In the example below the function will filter on the first column and return the total from column 5 based on the metric strength1

```
Group   Class1  <drop down  
Metric  Qty/Rx  <drop down  

Strength1   10.8        
Strength2   10.5        
Strength3   36      
Strength4   36.1
```

I believe sumifs are the way to go but I can not figure out how to integrate the second drop down to choose columns 3-5, any ideas would be warmly welcomed.

Comment: Use a **Pivot Table**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, I was told specifically to avoid using a pivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the data in cols **A** through **E** and the drop-downs in **G1** and **G2**.  List the strengths in **H3** through **H6**.  Then in **I3** enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A$2:A$16=G$1)*(B$2:B$16=H3)*(OFFSET(A$2:A$16,0,MATCH(G$2,$1:$1,0)-1)))
```

and copy downward:

[image]

This is an example of using `SUMPRODUCT()` with a variable column based on the column header.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to reply with a great solution. So that I better understand this solution could you tell me if I am understanding this correctly? You have three arrays, the first two arrays are logical (true or false, 1 or 0). For the third array you match G2 along row one which provides a value of X for the column reference which then allows the multiplication and then summing up? I wish this came to me a bit more intuitively, many thanks again.

Comment: @TheGoat  Your understanding is correct.  There are three factors in the `SUMPRODUCT()`. The **A** and **B** factors define the rows to sum over and the **OFFSET** factor defines the column to sum up!